# Cannot open phpMyAdmin setup wizard

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

While setting up MySQL I've got dozen of headaches, but nothing hurts as much as this one. I've been bashing my head around trying to install phpMyAdmin, followed all kinds of tutorials (they pretty much all said the same) but if something can go wrong it probably will.

When trying to open the setup wizard(from browser) by going to localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php (Step 4. in tutorial below, part when trying to invoke setup wizard) I get "Web page not avaiable" thing. Now when i just type localhost/ in browser I get the "It Works!" page.

I've followed the steps from tutorial, and it all worked (until step 4). Also installed Apache and MySQL with their reference tutorial at beginning(worked without any problem)

From what I've got I assume apache is set-up correctly since it shows "It Works!" page, but somehow it cant access the rest of the path phpmyadmin/setup/index.php

What did I do wrong?

---

Tutorial I followed:

- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/install-phpmyadmin/

Some basic info you might need:

- PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.6 (cli)
- MySQL 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1 (Ubuntu)
- Apache2 Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
- phpMyAdmin 4.3.6-all_languages pack from their website(extracted to `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/phpmyadmin` )
- OS: Linux Mint 16 32bit
- Browser: Chromium

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file and see if it's there.

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

If its there just specify the full path to your extension directory.

```
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"
```

According to me this will make this error solved.
Hope this helps you

Comment: It has `extension_dir = "ext"` , but where is `php/ext` on linux ?

Comment: Try to replace it with extension_dir = "your full path to extension folder"

Comment: yeah I got that, but I don't know where it is located. Found something where it says it's in `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions` but I dont have `php` dir, let alone `extensions`. Could it be that I didn't install php properly or `ext` folder is somewhere else ?

Comment: got ext dir with `php-config --extension-dir`. But in php.ini it says that `extension_dir="ext"` is for Windows...